# No module named 'PySide' when using Mu

Tags: python, pyperclip, mu

I've read all the other questions referencing this issue and tried the solutions but can't seem to get `pyperclip` working in Mu.

When I try running:

```py
>import pyperclip 
>pyperclip.copy('Hello, world') 
>pyperclip.paste()
```

I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andy/.local/share/mu/mu_venv-38-20210813-134953/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andy/mu_code/.py", line 3, in <module>
    pyperclip.copy('hello')
  File "/home/andy/.local/share/mu/mu_venv-38-20210813-134953/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 658, in lazy_load_stub_copy
    copy, paste = determine_clipboard()
  File "/home/andy/.local/share/mu/mu_venv-38-20210813-134953/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 582, in determine_clipboard
    import qtpy  # check if qtpy is installed
  File "/home/andy/.local/share/mu/mu_venv-38-20210813-134953/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Comment: What platform are you running on (macos/windows/linux (which))? How did you install mu? How did you install pyperclip?

Comment: You need to install PySide: https://pypi.org/project/PySide/

Comment: When I try to install PySide (pip pyside2) I get this message:
<pre>Requirement already satisfied: pyside2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: shiboken2==5.15.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyside2) (5.15.2)
</pre>

Comment: I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.2).  I installed mu by typing the following into the command prompt: 'pip3 install mu-editor==1.1.0b5'.

Comment: Seems pyperclip is working in IDLE3 but not Mu.  Thoughts?

Comment: Eureka!!!  I needed to install xclip and xsel manually for some reason.  Works now!  THANKS!